# Setting anchor link to an address in Laravel, gives error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-blade

In my Laravel application, when I am trying to link the username of the person who has posted in the website with his profile page, with the code:

```
<div class="media-body"><a href="@{{ post.user.profileUrl }}">@{{ post.user.name }}</a>
```

It is giving the error:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
>
> 1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

But, when I am trying to print `@{{ post.user.profileUrl }}` it is giving the right address, also in the json response, it is giving the right address, and going to the address is also reaching the specific location.

So, I don’t think it is some problem with post.user.profileUrl, as it seems to work fine, it seems to be some problem with using it with href, the address of the error in Google Chrome is:

http://localhost:8000/%7B%7B%20post.user.profileUrl%20%7D%7D

and the address should have been

http://localhost:8000/users/2 where 2 refers to the id of the user, which I am passing to the user through Vue.js

Comment: `post.user.profileUrl` is not a valid route. What are you trying to do? Create the link from ajax using your own JS Templating engine? (handlebars/mustache/etc)

Comment: I am using Vue.js, and yes, Ajax to do this, as stated post.user.profileUrl gives the right address, the problem is with adding to href or something @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Your template is trying to interprete it like ```http://localhost:8000/%7B%7B%20post.user.profileUrl%20%7D%7D``` where %20 is as space and %7B is opening curly bracket ({)and %7D is closing curly bracket (}). The problem is you're not able to print the value of variable ```post.user.profileUrl```. Try printing it in a span to check if it is working?

Comment: OK. Try ```<a href="post.user.profileUrl">```. Check if it is working?

Comment: Also check ```<pre>@{{post | json}}</pre>``` at the bottom of your template. Can you post the JSON here in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `@{{ post.user.profileUrl }}` is not parsing. `%7B%7B%20post.user.profileUrl%20%7D%7D` is ASCII representation of `{{ post.user.profileUrl }}`

Check if the code is in `.blade.php` file. If it is, you should look into JS template engine if you're using any.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks

> The @ symbol will be removed by Blade; however, {{ name }} expression will remain untouched by the Blade engine, allowing it to instead be rendered by your JavaScript framework

Comment: Actually it's the issue with Vue 2(The javascript library, I am using), they no longer allow usage inside quotes("), so I have put up the right answer, you can check that, thanks a lot for your answer, though

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a `$post` model in your view. When you setup relationships between the model `Post` and `User` you can link to them through the following:

```
<a href="{{ url('/@'.$post->user->profileUrl) }}">@{{ $post->user->name }}</a>
```

This will turn the users `profileUrl` into a valid link. But therefor you had to setup relationships in the Models.

Post model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Users', 'id', 'user_id');
    //first parameter is the Model class
    //send is the id of the user table
    //thirth is the user_id in the post table
}
```

And in the User model:

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Posts', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Yeah I tried yours, and it didn't work, actually it's the issue with Vue 2, they no longer allow usage inside quotes("), so I have put up the right answer, you can check that, thanks a lot for your answer, though

Answer (score 0):

Try this... this should definitely work for you

```
@verbatim
  <div class="media-body">
    <a href="{{ post.user.profileUrl }}">
      {{ post.user.name }}
    </a>
  </div>
@endverbatim
```

Comment: @Ronit Did you try my answer? I am sure this should work.

Comment: Yeah I tried yours, and it didn't work, actually it's the issue with Vue 2, they no longer allow usage inside quotes("), so I have put up the right answer, you can check that, thanks a lot for your answer, though

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem, the issue is with the javascript library, I am using, known as vue.js, it used to allow usage inside quotes, but in vue 2, they don't, so there is a turnaround for this,

```
<a :href="post.user.profileUrl">@{{ post.user.name }}</a>
```

and this works fine.

Thanks to all the people who contributed by answering...